# How to create face that "passes through"?

Tags: faces

What is the way to define a face that does nothing but "pass through" properties of the text it is applied to?

E.g. in the [`quick-peek`](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/quick-peek) package, [`quick-peek-background-face`](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/quick-peek/blob/master/quick-peek.el#L56) is applied to all text passed to `quick-peek-show`. I'd like `quick-peek-background-face` to do nothing but allow the properties of the text it's given to show.

**Example**:

The following has face `font-lock-doc-face` if we comment out this [offending call to `font-lock-append-text-property`](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/quick-peek/blob/master/quick-peek.el#L156):

```el
(quick-peek-show (propertize "foo" 'font-lock-face 'font-lock-doc-face))
```

Is there a value to `quick-peek-background-face` can be set to such that it allows `font-lock-doc-face` to pass through?

Comment: Sorry, but I, for one, have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: What's unclear? There is a face that is applied to some text which already has properties. I want to define the face such that it does nothing except allow existing properties to pass through, i.e. the face should be a "no-op".

Comment: Text-properties and overlays (quickpeek) behave differently -- overlays can have priorities where one can trump another, positive or negative (but negative are not officially supported as of the last time I read the documentation) -- text-properties are trumped by the most recent in time without ability to set priorities.  I am unaware of any transparent face.  Faces can also inherit from other faces.  Font-lock has the ability to ad `t` to a face being applied so that it trumps other faces, or gets buried.  If you have a real life minimal working example, please consider editing the question.

Comment: Added an example. I also suspect there's an issue with `face` having higher priority than `font-lock-face`? Why do both exist, anyway?

Comment: Property `font-lock-face` was created because font-lock does not play nicely with other uses of property `face`. As font-lock highlighting was used more and more, some people forgot about or didn't care about non-font-lock uses of faces (property `face`). See [this explanation](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary#InteractionWithFontLock) in library [`highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el).

Comment: Cool; so there's no solution to this problem then? If so, I'll open a PR against `quick-peek` to not use `quick-peek-background-face`.

Comment: Opened a [PR](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/quick-peek/pull/5).